# Apache deflates .xml.gz files

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, gzip, compression, mod-deflate

I noticed an error in google webmaster tools regarding a gzipped version of a sitemap. Turns out the `sitemap.xml.gz` file is gzipped twice: one upon creation (as it should be) and another time when being served.

The `.htaccess` file has this rule

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
```

which I thought wouldn't match a gzipped XML file, but apparently it does as removing this solves the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.xml.gz` filetype may be defined as being an xml file (e.g. with forcetype in a filesmatch block) - which would cause Apache to match it to the type above.

I think you can get around that by adding an exception, above it:

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ".xml.gz$" no-gzip dont-vary

You might want to see [HowToForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2_mod_deflate) for more exceptions to add.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: This works perfectly, although I haven't found anything in the htaccess or in the vhost configuration which would force gzip files to have `application/xml` MIME type